# Could not send mail from godaddy mail servier in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to send mail using GoDaddy mail server with SMTPClient in ASP.NET and my code is below , I have tried all the ports in GoDaddy but i couldn't send a mail

My code:

```
    try
    {

        //Mail Message
        MailMessage mM = new MailMessage();
        //Mail Address
        mM.From = new MailAddress("xxx@sender.com");
        //receiver email id
        mM.To.Add("xxx@receiver.com");
        //subject of the email
        mM.Subject = "your subject line will go here";
        mM.Body = "Body of the email";
        mM.IsBodyHtml = true;
        //SMTP client

       SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient();

        //credentials to login in to hotmail account
        sC.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

        //port number for Hot mail
        sC.Port = 25;
        sC.Host = "smtpout.asia.secureserver.net";
        sC.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

        //enabled SSL
        sC.EnableSsl = false;
        sC.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

        sC.Timeout = 40000;

        //Send an email
        sC.Send(mM);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var temp = ex.Message;
    }
```

I have also used port no 465 with enablessl = true but no success

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Yes , I am getting an exception like  "**The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: authentication required**" this is for port number 25

And when i use port number 465 with EnableSsl=true , I get an exception "**{"Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed."}**"

Comment: try port 587 and enablessl=true

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too and found a solution.

The problem is that GoDaddy uses Implicit SSL (SMTPS) and this is NOT supported with System.Net.Mail.
It should be possible to use a GoDady Relay account, but then you can only send 250 emails per day AND the email sent will be SPAM unvisible at receiver side!

Then I found an open source library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/netimplicitssl/

You can get this package via NuGet in Visual Studio.
Search for: **Aegis Implicit Mail**.
I can tell you that this works perfectly !

```
private void _SendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        var mail = "YourEmail@YourGoDaddyWebsite.com";
        var host = "smtpout.europe.secureserver.net";
        var user = "YourEmail@YourGoDaddyWebsite.com";
        var pass = "YourGoDaddyPassword!";

        //Generate Message 
        var message = new MimeMailMessage();
        message.From = new MimeMailAddress(mail);
        message.To.Add("receiver@website.com");
        message.Subject = "Subject Text...";
        message.Body = "Body Text...";

        //Create Smtp Client
        var mailer = new MimeMailer(host, 465);
        mailer.User = user;
        mailer.Password = pass;
        mailer.SslType = SslMode.Ssl;
        mailer.AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationType.Base64;

        //Set a delegate function for call back
        mailer.SendCompleted += compEvent;
        mailer.SendMailAsync(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string msg = ex.Message;
    }
}
private void compEvent(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.UserState != null)
        Console.Out.WriteLine(e.UserState.ToString());

    Console.Out.WriteLine("is it canceled? " + e.Cancelled);

    if (e.Error != null)
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Error : " + e.Error.Message);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you should note you cannot sent non-html, or plain text emails. The message.IsBodyHtml member does not seem to work currently.